# itext nested table width

Tags: c#, itext

Is there a way to control the width of a nested table? It seems to default to the width of the outer table for me.

-Rod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PdfPTable](http://api.itextpdf.com/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfPTable.html).[setTotalWidth(float)](http://api.itextpdf.com/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfPTable.html#setTotalWidth%28float%29) for the overall width all at once, or setTotalWidth(float[])] to set the individual absolute column widths (and table width by extension).

The former needs some information on relative column widths if you want to do anything but have evenly spaced columns.

If you're not using PdfPTable, you'll need to change.  You have much more control this way.